# MVVM - I should maintain data in Model or ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, uwp

I'm doing a C# application using WPF. I'm trying to follow correctly the MVVM pattern because (especially with C#/WPF) is very useful.

My app is designed in 3 "big" parts, as the MVVM model says:

- The view, in XAML -> The MainWindow.xaml
- The ViewModel, in C# -> MainWindow.xaml.cs
- The Model, in C# -> A my **static** class named Register.cs

It's a strong pattern, and it's working good.

My software manage lists of custom object: I press a button on the View, the ViewModel start a method (on Model) that retrieve **lists** of data from database and I bind them on the View side (on a ListView, in WPF).

All is working good. But, even after reading a lot about MVVC pattern, I cannot understand a thing: where I should **memorize** these lists?

For now, I'm declaring these lists on Model and they can be retrieved by simply calling them through the ViewModel but I don't know if it's the right approach.

I need to maintain these lists and a lot of others strings (like current username and things like that) until I close the software (or I need to save them).

All data come from INI or DBs, and I don't know where I should "temporary" memorize them, if on the ViewModel (why? because its the View that interact with them) or in the Model? (isn't smarter to retain the data "near" the place where you got them?)

Also,in the future, I would like to **port** the software in UWP or Mono, so I should simplify myself the jump. Also, in that case, I think I will have to discharge all the works I've done on the ViewModel.

Where I should memorize all "temporary" data used by the software? In the M or in the VM?

Comment: It's more a matter of 'when' you write through from the VM to the M. Various models are possible, depending on business rules and whether you have [Save]/[Cancel] buttons or not.

Answer (score 1):

The way I think about where to put something is like this: answer the question if it is a business (data) concern or a UI (presentation) concern. First will go in the model, the second in the view model.

Comment: so, are you saying that current user name would be in the ViewModel ?